# how to align column content in css

Tags: html, css

In the following html code I created a row with two columns.The first column i have an image and on the second I have my heading and a paragraph.

```
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
              <img src="image/beds.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">
              <h2>Nevex has the experiencce</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates velit, inventore praesentium. Delectus nulla, voluptates excepturi earum minima eligendi cumque ullam, opdfgdtio nostrum ipsa maiores cupiditate facilis sint debitis aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia id beatae nostrum ducimus possimus, odit eligendi fuga perspiciatis placeat nisi facilis unde adipisci illo fugit doloremque, at porro magni, perferendis?</p>
          </div>

      </div>
```

And next is my styling code:

```
    .row {
     margin: 0 -10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
     .row:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 0;
     }
     [class*="col-"] {
      padding: 10px;
     }
     @media all and ( min-width: 600px ) {
     .row {
     display: table;
     table-layout: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     }
     [class*="col-"] {
      display: table-cell;
     }    
    .col-1{
     width:100%;
     }
    .col-6{
     width:50%;
     }
    }
```

How can I alter the size of the image with responsiveness and align the content of both columns?
Meaning that the image would decrease a bit in terms of height and the content of the other column would also be in the middle of the div.

Comment: A picture worth a 1,000 lines of code, and a jsFiddle worth 1,000 pictures :)

Comment: If you could post a working example online, it would be easier to play around with, and understand the problem. Finding the problem just by looking at the code is much harder than one might think :)

Comment: Please check the link: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/2x7mdefg/.
Basically I would like both clumns to have the same size so that all contents are centered and aligned.
Unfortunately you won't see the image but hope I made some sense.

Comment: Does this make sense? https://jsfiddle.net/2x7mdefg/1/

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to use image as a background to that div, and once you do it, you can give it a width:100%.

If you are using bootstrap, you can add the class="img-responsive" and it will automatically adapt to the width of the screen

Comment: Am using media queries for this case.

Comment: when saw the class="col-6" I thought bootstrap. Well, another solution would be creating mediaqueries for different screen sizes and givind the picture a width:100%. However, you would have to specify the width of the div containing it